# Cross domain iframe are forbidden

Tags: iframe

I want to use iframe reference a website, but the other prohibited me use js as follows:

```
/* frame busting */
if (top !== self) {
    top.location.replace(location);
    alert("prohibited!");
    $('body').html('');
}
```

how could i do?

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't know what that means

Comment: You can't, if cross site access is not granted. That is the whole point of it!

Comment: Is there any solutions?